The Graceful Tree Conjecture
I cam across two papers regarding the Graceful Tree conjecture (or KRR conjecture), which claim a proof.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.07614
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.03178
The conjecture asks wether given a finite tree $G=(V,E)$ with $n+1$ vertices and $n$ edges, it is possible to assign labels to the vertices i.e a function $f(V):V\to V$ such that the induced labels on the edges $f(E):E\to \{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$ given by $(i,j)\mapsto |f(i)-f(j)|$ is a bijection onto $\{0,1,\ldots n-1\}$ (we identify $E=\{0,1,\ldots n-1\}$).
In the first one the author proceeds by contradiction and in the second he proceeds in a constructive manner.
Essentially both papers proof boil down to what the author calls the composition lemma. This has two forms (lemma $5$ in the first paper and lemma $24$ in the second). I will restate them.
Let $H=\{f:\{0,1,\ldots n-1\}\to \{0,1,\ldots n-1\}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(i)<i$ for $i\neq 0$}.
(Composition lemma version 1):
Let $f,g\in H$ then we have $$max _{\sigma\in S_n}|\{|\sigma f g \sigma^{-1}(i)-i| , i\in \{0,1,\ldots n-1\}\}|\leq max _{\sigma\in S_n}|\{|\sigma f  \sigma^{-1}(i)-i| , i\in \{0,1,\ldots n-1\}\}|$$
(Commposition lemma version 2):
Let $f\in H$
then we have $$max _{\sigma\in S_n}|\{|\sigma f f \sigma^{-1}(i)-i| , i\in \{0,1,\ldots n-1\}\}|\leq max _{\sigma\in S_n}|\{|\sigma f  \sigma^{-1}(i)-i| , i\in \{0,1,\ldots n-1\}\}|$$
Let us pick the first version. In the begining of the proof the author remarks if there exists  functions $f,g\in H$ s.t. $max _{\sigma\in S_n}|\{|\sigma g  \sigma^{-1}(i)-i| , i\in \{0,1,\ldots n-1\}\}|<n$ we can construct $f',g'\in H$ to contradict the first version of the composition lemma.
The proof then proceeds with the assumption that for $f,g\in H$ we have $max _{\sigma\in S_n}|\{|\sigma fg  \sigma^{-1}(i)-i| , i\in \{0,1,\ldots n-1\}\}|=n$
Why can we make such a claim? It seems claiming this is equivalent the to the KRR conjecture itself.
It seems there is some similar problem in the second version.

See also https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/54427/is-gnangs-proof-of-graceful-tree-conjecture-correct
